# How can I find the "Count" of a user input if the input is classified in different sections?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been going at this function for a few days and this is my first real program (I am learning to code on my own). I have used for and while loops and things of that sort and decided it was time to put my skills to the test, and my friend gave me a prompt to try out. I have user imputed "scores" and I must classify these scores within a ranking system. 
This is my code thus far:

```
def grade_scores():
    count = int(input('Enter amount of scores: '))  
    print('Each will be entered one per line')      
    scoreList = []                                  
    for i in range(1, count+1):                    
        scoreList.append(int(input('Enter score: ')))
    print("GRADE  COUNT  PERCENTAGE")
    for grade in ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'F'):
        return grade
        A = 'A'
        B = 'B'
        C = 'C'
        D = 'D'
        F = 'F'
    for score in (scoreList):
        if score >= 91:
            score = A
            count[0] += 1  # Increase index 0 (Corresponds to value A) by 1
        elif score >= 81 and score <=90:
            score = B
            count[1] += 1
        elif score >= 71 and score <=80:
            score = C
            count[2] += 1
        elif score >= 61 and score <=70:
            score = D
            count[3] += 1
        else: #<= 60
            score = F
            count[4] += 1
```

At the end my goal is to print like this in a column formation, I understand this is not correct yet and i need to set up the count to be able to print

```
    print("GRADE  COUNT")
    print(grade, count)

grade_scores()
```

So my question is how can I format my "count" to classify the user input or  am I possibly on the right track?

Comment: Use a dictionary to keep track of the counts by grade, not an array.

Comment: `return grade` in the first `for` loop will exit from the function immediately.

Comment: Why do you think you need that `for grade in` loop in the first place?

Comment: You don't need `and score <= 90` in the `elif` clause -- you can't get to that line if `score >= 91` because that gets matched by the previous `if`.

Comment: You can't assign to `count[0]`. `count` is an integer, because it's the number of scores that the user entered in response to the first question.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track, but have some fundamental flaws in your code.

```
def get_grades():
    count = int(input("how many scores? "))

    scores = []
    for _ in range(count):
        score = int(input("Score: "))
        scores.append(score)
    # this whole section can be rewritten as:
    # # scores = [int(input("Score: ")) for _ in range(count)]

    result = {"A":0, "B":0, "C":0, "D":0, "F":0}
    for score in scores:
        if score > 90:
            result["A"] += 1
        elif 80 < score <= 90:
            result["B"] += 1
        elif 70 < score <= 80:
            result["C"] += 1
        elif 60 < score <= 70:
            result["D"] += 1
        else:
            result["F"] += 1
    return (scores, result)
```

This will give you a tuple of:

```
([the list of raw scores], {a dictionary of grade counts})
```

Comment: Thank you! but how can I have the function return the result?

Comment: I seem to get the type error " unorderable types: list() < int()", so it means that somewhere along the way the code seems to become a list, but I'm not sure where this is happening

Comment: I've seen you ask a couple questions in the comments, then delete and ask a different question, so I think I'm just going to let you reason with it for another little while!! My code as-written is tested and working as intended. I describe the output below the code.

Comment: Yes I am still fiddling with it, and trying to make it work, I'm sorry that I'm not very good at this. My goal is to print the scores and result in two columns but when I attempt to print the scores and result it doesn't work properly and now i realize it is my fault for not including that into the original question.

Comment: @Jennga the function returns a tuple as described at the bottom of my answer. You can do `scores, counts = get_grades()` to automagically unpack it.

Comment: Oh! thank you so much for clarifying, I'm sorry for not realizing it earlier. Okay I believe I almost have it, but I'm not sure because the code for some reason is in a continuous loop from  "count = int(input('Enter amount of scores: '))" to  "scores = [int(input("Enter score: ")) for i in range(count)]" ( i had figured switching to the condensed version would fix the problem)

Comment: @Jennga are you still having trouble?